# Robot Framework Do not execute part of Teardown on Fatal Error

Tags: automation, robotframework

Is it possible to exclude part of the Teardown to be executed in case the whole test was failed with Fatal Error?

Looking for some buildin solution, have many teardowns (for each test different teardown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to pass "status" variable and checking it on Teardown(s) keywords.

In case of fatal error, "status" = true and then validate in teardown keyword.